# Manipulate an input field

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, firefox2

Is it possible to remove an input but show the value with Greasemonkey? Or disable it?  For example:

```
<input name="prio" type="text" value="285" disabled="disabled">
```

I have no idea how to write any userscript. :(

It is for the PC in my company and I am not able to work with jQuery or edit the original source code.

First take a look for better understanding:

The code looks like that: http://jsfiddle.net/gv3XF/

But I want it like that: http://jsfiddle.net/gv3XF/1/

I tried it with *Stylish* but with that, I can only hide the input. I still need the value for result.

The input always is called `name="prio"` but the number from the value is changing.

What I want is to "kill" the input but show the result of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just "kill" the input.  If you do, then the necessary data might not get sent to the server when you submit the form.

So, ***hide*** the input and show its value.  Here's a complete script that uses the awesome power of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to do that:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Make Priority more user friendly
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//--- The @grant is to subvert a huge design flaw, introduced with GM version 1.

var oldInput    = $("input[name=prio]");
var priorityVal = oldInput.val ();
oldInput.after ('<b id="gmPriorityValue">' + priorityVal + '</b>');
oldInput.remove ();

$("#gmPriorityValue").before ('<input type="hidden" name="prio">');
$("input[name=prio]").val (priorityVal);
```

Change the `@include` value to match your site(s).

Note that you can't change an `<input>`s type, so we delete the old input and create a new one with the same value, but hidden.

---

---

Re: `do that without jquery? the pc has no internet connection`:

You're going to sneak the script file onto the PC, right? :)
Download and sneak jQuery onto it too.  With the jQuery file and the userscript file in the same folder, change the `@require` line to:

```
// @require     jquery.min.js
```

Then the script will install just fine, no internet connection required.

---

---

Re: `maybe the easiest way is to disable the input field`:

Okay, the script to do that is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Make Priority more user friendly
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant       GM_getValue
// ==/UserScript==

var oldInput = document.querySelector ("input[name=prio]");
oldInput.setAttribute ("disabled", "disabled");
```

---

#### Update:

Extremely crucial information was omitted from the question -- mainly that this is meant for Firefox 2.0(!!!) and Greasemonkey 0.8. Given that, change the code for the last script to:

```
var oldInput = document.getElementsByName ("prio");
oldInput[0].setAttribute ("disabled", "disabled");
```

It should work, but it's impossible to test, and [compatibility tables don't even cover such an obsolete browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html).

Comment: hi brock! thanks for the quick response... is there a way to do that without jquery? the pc has no internet connection for security reason. and i can't change the source-code to add the jquery path in the header

Comment: maybe the easiest way is to disable the input field. is that possible? <input name="prio" type="text" value="285" disabled="disabled">

Comment: Right. That's a complete script. You can tell it doesn't use jQuery because it doesn't have a `@require` directive, in this case.

Comment: cool it works! do you think your code works with firefox 2.0 and greasemonkey 0.8? i will try it tomorrow at work and will answer than! :D thanks for the moment :D

Comment: Firefox 2.0 and Greasemonkey 0.8!!!!  **You need to state that up front!**  I'm not sure. the compatibility tables don't go back that far for FF.

Comment: damn.. it doesnt work.. i made a mistake :D i had a disabled attribute in the html.. for testing it on my pc i can set // @include     * right?

Comment: i found the error.. your code works only online and not on localhost.. the server is localhost too.. works fine @ http://jsfiddle.net/gv3XF/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16060/discussion-between-brock-adams-and-bernte)